# nodejs server - how to load file in memory to use in Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good Morning Everyone,

First, I am not a full dev, this is a hobby, I'm using a NodeJS / ExpressJS server (in ES6) to serve an application I made for 2000 people. This was all reversed engineered. But I am in a rush to fix the app, as the normal API point I was using is now going down, I had to rewrite loads of things.

The last thing I need to fix most problems I have; I am using 2 JSON files that contains about 50MB data each. Obviously I don't want to load those everytime in memory.

The way I wrote my code, I'm using server.js to load all my API points that people can call.
Then I broke my functions withing Modules (files in different folders) to keep things clean.

Here are the questions.

1. Can I load those 2 files in Memory and access them from my Modules, if so how?
2. Removed my second question for update file - Will do it differently then with nodejs

As it was counter productive to try and make it work when I have another solution

Comment: A memory cache could be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi pSyToR if you can load your json files and then export them both. other files can then import them and edit the values on them if needed, you can also use `globalThis` to make them globally available

I have an example below of both

via exports

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

const fileA = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fileA.json', { encoding: 'ascii' }))
const fileB = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fileB.json', { encoding: 'ascii' }))

export { fileA, fileB }
```

Importing

```
import { fileA, fileB } from 'path/to/file-handler.js'
```

via globalThis

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

const fileA = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fileA.json', { encoding: 'ascii' }))
const fileB = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fileB.json', { encoding: 'ascii' }))

globalThis.fileA = fileA
globalThis.fileB = fileB
```

Importing

```
var data = globalThis.fileA.data
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that totally make sense... What about removing them from Memory during an update and putting them back? I have a call to my server that launches a process to delete the files and download the new versions...

Comment: Should I actually run a daemon on the server instead - That does the same check if there is a new version, turn off the server, update the files restart it?

Comment: you can use `Object.assign` to copy over new values or if your using the `globalThis` method reassign the variables

Comment: Hi @7Bit thanks for your answer, I would make sure to mention something in your answer... Put a "file" name for your import example, and show that in the importing your are pointing the "export" file not the actualy JSON file that I was trying to put in memory... Took me a bit of time to figure this one out... Other than that Import Export works great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to delete the file from the memory management

`delete require.cache[require.resolve('FILE')];`

Comment: Since this is running on Docker - I think a restart from time to time will be worth it. So I will make the update external to the actualy node server and send a rebuilt to the machine when there is an update